# Trying to sort tsv files by one column using powershell

Tags: sorting, powershell

I have several .tsv files that I need to merge and then sort by only one column. Unfortunately that column is presented in digits (no decimals), but different length. 
I used the following script:

```
$a=get-content -path\*filename*.tsv -encoding ASCII
$a|sort-object [int]column1|select-object -first ($a.count - $fileCount)|out-file -filepath -encoding ASCII
```

Unfortunately the outfile still not sorted. Any suggestion?
P.S  Actually it is sorted inside of individual files, but since several files were merged in variable $a, the total output is not sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Not tested.

```
$filename = 'c:\somedir\somefilename.tsv'
$ht=@{}
filter Get-Record { if ($ht[$_] -ne $HeaderLine) {$ht[$_]} }
$HeaderLine = $null
$counter = 0

get-content -path\*filename*.tsv -encoding ASCII |
 foreach { 
           if (-not $HeaderLine) 
             { $HeaderLine = $_ }

            $counter++

            $ht["$($_.split("`t")[1])$counter"] = $_                

         }

$HeaderLine | set-content $filename  #header
$ht.keys | Sort | Get-Record | add-content $filename
```

It should sort on whatever column you use from the `$_.split("`t")` array,

Comment: Should not $HeaderLine be defined earlier? Getting the error The variable '$HeaderLine' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.

Comment: $HeaderLine should get set by the first line of the first file read.

Comment: Unfortunately it is failing with the error I described. When I physically defined the header by listing all the columns, it worked, but I should not have tondo that. And the biggest issue, it is very slow. Took 35 min to process less than 10 files. They are quite large. Any suggestions to improve the performance or should I move to vb.net?

Comment: It sounds like you have strict mode set.  I added a line to define $HeaderLine before it's used in the IF test.  As far as speeding it up, I'd need to know more about the data.  Is the field you're sorting on going to be unique for each record? If not, will there by relatively many or few records with the same value?

Comment: Yes I did have the strict mode set. Seems like it is working with this minor tweak. The sort field should be unique, at least to the best of my knowledge. And the number of files close to 100 with probably 150000 records per each file. Number of columns is quite substantial, over 60. And I assume I could add out-file -filepath $filename -encoding ASCII command after ($ht.keys | sort) -notmatch $HeaderLine | Get-Record ?

Comment: Just a little explanation, if it is possible. Do I need to add anything into sort command ( split array column expression) or it should be specified in ht.keys command? I am sorry , it is just absolutely new to me.

Comment: You don't have to add anything.  What it's doing is creating a hash table that uses the field you want to sort on as the key, and the entire line as the value. Once you have that you just sort the keys, and then spit out the hash table values in that order.

Comment: Just noticed and fixed a bug in that script. It won't exclude multiple headers as originally posted.

Comment: So, if you I need for example column 7 as the sort key, the hash table should have [6], correct?

Comment: Yes. You're basically splitting the line on the tabs, and choosing one of the split elements to be the hash table key.  Then you sort the keys. It isn't being converted to csv, and the output will be the original input line, so the output will still be tsv format.

Comment: Ran very fast, but created only one output record, and expected a lot - lot more. Had the input of 10 files with lots of records in each of them

Comment: The only change I made was added the real path to the output and input file. Now, what I did not do is specify the real column number I need to sort by, and since the first occurrence is the same , it produced only one file. makes sense to me.

Comment: I think it is working now as I expected. The only thing I do not need the header on the final result file. Can I just use the select-object cmdlet and skip 1, or it is possible to do with one of the commands already in the script? I did a quick get-help and did not find anything

Comment: The header is being added to the final result by the next to last line in that script. If you remove that, you won't get a header in the final result.

Comment: Removed it, works really fast. I did a quick count and found that I am missing couple of records from the total. You once asked if there is a possibility of duplication. Let's say, if there are. Could it be possible to included them in the final output? Trying to figure out what could cause the issue with loosing records.

Comment: Duplicate keys would account for missing records.  You'll either need to make the hash table values collections or arrays (which is going to slow it down), or find a way to make the keys unique.  I added a counter, and appended the value of that to the field value being used for the keys.  Hopefully that will eliminate the duplicate records without slowing it down too much.

Comment: mjolinor, was too fast to proclaim the total success, I am definitely loosing 1 record from each file, and when displaying the counter it is giving me one more that actual records written. It does one extra read I guess. Bur more worrisome is to loose one record from each file.

Comment: It's supposed to lose one record from each file - the header.

Comment: what I meant that it is loosing one more besides the header. let's say I had 10 files with 14001 in it (one for the header). then output expected to be 140000 (losing one for the header from each file). the actual result on the output file is 139990. It is easier to explain with real numbers

Comment: You're the only one with the data files, so you're the only one that can say which records are missing.  I'm not going to try and debug that blind.

Comment: mjolinor, I must say you were right. The last file was smaller, nothing was lost. I have made some changes to have the counter to show my real output numbers. And that was it. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, probably better to import them using import-csv. Try this:

```
gci *filename*.tsv|foreach{$a+=import-csv $_.fullname -delimiter "`t"}
```

Now you have an array that you can sort by whatever field you want, and can use:

```
$a|convertto-csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation|select -Skip 1|Out-File  output.tsv
```

Edited to remove header output.

Comment: the only thing is that each entry in array will have the column headers, and I need to remove all of them in the output file. And would not the existence of a header restart the sort for each file, I only need the final output file to be sorted. And once again the column itself could have different length :8-9-10

Comment: Did you try my code? Is there a problem with it that you are seeing? Column length should not matter, if they are truly tab separated values it will find the values correctly. Assuming all files have the same column headers it will build one large array, and you can output that to a single file with one header line.

Comment: I did not try it yet, but I will. Just want to understand, the output.tsv file will have sorted file with one header? Need to get rid of that header also

Comment: Answer updated, it will no longer output a header line, so you just get the data. Do the files you are reading from have header lines? If not this will not work, as the Import-CSV won't work right as it is written right now.

Comment: Tried to run in it in steps. gci command produced the following error:

Comment: sorry, no errors, but could not update my comment, the code runs forever for only handful of files, but in real life it is going to be maybe a hundred. It hosed my machine, takes about 7 gb of RAM, and what used to run couple of minutes, taking forever. Is it possible to tweak for performance?

Comment: Plus the file size is 5 times larger that it used to be. And I would love to keep the file in tsv format, not csv with every field wrapped in double quotes. But must admit it is sorted properly

Comment: The variable '$a' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set. that is the error, and interesting I had this error when I was trying to post it, then it ran, now it came back